# SQLServer + PHP.ini

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to create a PHP connecting to SQL Server 2008 but the server returns the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect ()
```

Looked in many places and they all say to go in PHP.ini and uncomment the line:

```
extension = php_mysql.dll
```

But my php.ini file doesn't have this line.

This is my current code, but I've tried several others:

```
<? php 
mssql_connect ("192.168.2.7", "sa", "5c n9r1n7 @ # @ dm") or die ("Could not connect to server"); 
mssql_select_db ("fd_585b0f87") or die ("Unable to select database"); 
mssql_close (); 
print "Connection OK"; 
>
```

I've tried this also:

```
<? php 
$ server = "192.168.2.7"; 
$ database = "fd_585b0f87"; 
$ user = "sa"; 
$ password = "5c n9r1n7 @ # @ dm"; 


$ conn = mssql_connect ($ server, $ user, $ password); 
$ conn = mssql_select_db ("$ database", $ connection); 


if ($ conn) {
echo "One connection"; 


} 
>
```

Anyone know any way to fix this error? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to uncomment the line:

```
;php_mssql.dll
```

Not

```
;php_mysql.dll
```

One is for Microsoft SQL Server (php_mssql.dll) whilst the other is for MySQL (php_mysql.dll).

If that fails, you probably don't have the MSSQL drivers installed.  [This link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20098) provides instructions on how to install the MSSQL drivers which will enable you to interface with MSSQL from within your PHP script.

Comment: Thank you Friend, But my php.ini don't have this line too. Should I install Something? Thank you again

Comment: After downloading the files, where should I put? Thank You

Comment: It needs to go into your PHP extensions directory.

Comment: Ok, so if i install this files, my php.ini will have this lane? Or i don't need more haha